# How do I remove a word from a url in Wordpress using .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In the site I'm building there is a `post-type` called "Focus". Since they need to url to be like `www.mysite.com/focus/page-post-name` I have the post type slug as "focus".

Of course the archive page is `www.mysite.com/focus` this is causing an issue since I need a specific page to be an archive page. Metaboxes are used to build and add settings to pages. I can't just create a page called "Focus" since that is reserved by the `post-type`.

My idea is to create a page called "Our Focus" resulting a URL of `www.mysite.com/our-focus`.

I'd like to just remove the "our-" from that url to make it appear that the archive is being used.

I've tried setting `has_archive` to false but that just reverts to using the archive.php page.

Comment: of course if there is another option I'm willing to try it. Always more than one way to do get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm mobile and working without access to a test server, so forgive any errors.

It sounds like you need mod_rewrite, it should be packaged with apache, but may be off. Typically you'll have to check the mods_enabled directory in your apache conf directory, or search your conf file for rewrite.

You'll need two lines in your htaccess at least.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/focus/?$ /our-focus/
```

First line is required to enable rewrite.
The second line is the rule declaration,  a regex to match, and a destination. The regex should only match focus, and direct you accordingly. Wordpress may take issue, but I think this will work.

Docs for reference

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You may need `RewriteBase` depending on setup. RewriteBase is typically used if there are virtualHosts or a different base url then the server expects.